# I need to cancel request if user waiting to long and start new one

Tags: python, server, request, artificial-intelligence, aiohttp

I am building telegram chat bot with aoigram so everything is asynchronous and I need connect openai
And once user send reuest and waiting to long or changing his mind I want him to be able to cancel it  and than start a new one if needed
so it should be cancel with /start
and here what I have

```
@dp.message_handler(Regexp(r'.*/start.*'), state='*')
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    global ongoing_tasks
    if chat_id in ongoing_tasks and not ongoing_tasks[chat_id].done():
        ongoing_tasks[chat_id].cancel()
        del ongoing_tasks[chat_id]
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state:
        await state.finish()
```

here user will send request

```
@dp.message_handler(state=TaskCreation.ImprovementDetails)
async def process_improvement_details(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    improvement_details = message.text
    global running_tasks

    chat_id = message.chat.id
    start_time = time.time()
    await message.answer('Треба подумати кілька секунд)')

    user_data = await state.get_data()
    description = user_data.get("description")
    response_text = ""
    if improvement_details != "":
        response_text = ""

        # improvement_details = None  # or some default value
    if chat_id in ongoing_tasks and not ongoing_tasks[chat_id].done():
        ongoing_tasks[chat_id].cancel()
    task = asyncio.create_task(
        send_request("generate_response/", {"text": message.text, "chat_id": chat_id})
    )
    ongoing_tasks[chat_id] = task
    try:
        response = await task
        await wait_for_response(response, message) # here just igame that appear once waiting for responce
   except asyncio.CancelledError:
            await message.answer("Task was cancelled.")
            return
    finally:
        # Cleanup the task from the tracking dictionary
        if chat_id in ongoing_tasks:
            del ongoing_tasks[chat_id]
```

and how I send request

````
    url = urljoin(BACKEND_URL, endpoint)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            async with session.post(url, json=data) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    return await response.json()
                else:
                    print(f"Error: Server responded with status code {response.status}")
                    return None
        except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
            print(f"Connection error: {e}")
            return None```



once I type /start to cancel it all during waiting for response here what I have


`Connection error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='46.101.4.220', port=32191): Max retries exceeded with url: /gen/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FCCD269790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
`


please help
````

Comment: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#timeouts

Comment: @matszwecja so user will send response and idea if user change his mind so he can just type /start and he will return back to main menu. as now I just receive error of 
Connection error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='', port=): Max retries exceeded with URL
because once user type /start it will reset history for which it should send another request to server #